# How can I access value in nested dictionary using a single key?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, pickle

Assuming that I have a nested dictionary, that is extracted from pickle file, that contains various levels, I would like to get the value by giving only the last key. Keys are unique considering own 'branch'.

The main problem is that I have multiple keys and levels:

```
 dict = {
    
    'A': {
        
        'X': {
            1: [...],
            2: [...]
        },
        
        'Y': {
            3: [...],
            4: [...]
        }
    }
    
    'B': {
        
        'G': {
            
            'H': {
                
                'Z': [...]
            }
        }
    }
    
    'C': [...]
 
 }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add an example of the dictionary

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal.  If your key is not unique you have to tell us which value(s) you want.

Comment: Why did you clear the accepted answer flag? Is anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that it does not work if we have multiple keys and levels

Comment: First of all, your dictionary has syntax issues. Second I still have no idea what you are looking for. May you just add a example after which key you are looking / what the expected result looks like? A dictionary does not have "branches", it has keys and values.

Comment: I load data from pickle to dictionary, which has multiple levels that have non uniform depth. I want to make a function that will return me a value based on last key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple solution would be a recusrive function that even works for nested, nested dictionarys

```
outer_dict = {'outer': {'inner': 10, 'even_inner': {'innerst': 25}}}
```

and the function:

```
def get_val(search_dict, key):
    """ recursive searching the dict """
    for elem in search_dict:
        if elem == key:
            return search_dict[elem]
        if isinstance(search_dict[elem], dict):
            retval = get_val(search_dict[elem], key)
            if retval is not None:
                return retval
```

```
value = get_val(outer_dict, 'innerst')
print(value)
>> 25
```

Problems:
if the key is not unique you will get only the first match. You will need a list to fill a values into if the key can be there more than once.

Please provide a example next time!

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if there is a singular key. How can I fix that? You can see example in the description

Comment: I edited to work for more than one key. But this solution still only works for unique keys, you will have to fill a list if this is not the intended usecase.

Comment: The keys are unique. Your new solution works, thank you very much!